# n4bg conusmes high cpu in AIX

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, aix, nfsclient

A process with name n4bg  (NFS client?)  in aix consumes  a high percentage of CPU continuously .OS is AIX 6.1.9

- What is this process actually with name n4bg and what is the use of this     process.
- What could be the reason for this  high CPU utilization around > 50%
  constantly.
- What could be the resolution to reduce the CPU %  in this case.

Comment: You might try `procldd <pid>` to collect information, but mainly just `kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: Or do a google-search: most likely you have to ask your IBM-contact for fix.